# Error 580022 retrieving PayKey from PayPal (invalid AccountID). What should be placed into the receiver's AccountID and where to find that info?

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to integrate a website with PayPal using AdaptivePayments for DigitalGoods and parallel payments. I'm using accountIDs instead of emails, but I don't know what should I use as my accountID. Everything I have tried so far gives me error 580022 and says that I have an invalid value for accountID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not all paypal accounts have account IDs, only business accounts. So I had to use emails instead of account IDs. And the account ID info can be found at the profile page, once you log into PayPal.